# How to insert a subprocess output into a variable

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I'm trying to work with Powershell in python and work with get-disk command
I tried to work with stdout and print it but the value of it is gone right after I use the Communicate() function
Here's my code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('get-disk')
print stdout
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using two scripting languages when you can do everything with `PowerShell` on its own? `PS C:\> Get-Disk` bam. done.

Comment: you are just opeining a powershell  process without parameters. I am not aware of any process that by default reads input parameters from stdin... did you google that? what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768790/stdin-to-powershell-script

Comment: Use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75175057/12780274`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, which will read the std output of your process
when starting the process with

```
proc=Popen('Some process',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout = proc.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as done below

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,PIPE,STDOUT
import subprocess
command="powershell.exe get-disk"

#This will open the command in a new console
proc=Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
read_stdout=[]
for lines in proc.stdout.readlines():
    read_stdout.append(lines)

print read_stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend `proc.stdout.read()` instead of `proc.communicate()`

What you want is something like this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe get-disk"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.read())
proc.stdout.close()
```